Making Queue class singleton is incorrect?
QueueFactory
/**
 * QueueFactory.ts
 *
/

/**
 * `QueueType` is an enum representing the different types of queues that can be created using the `QueueFactory`.
 */
export enum QueueType {
  RABBITMQ = 'rabbitMQ'
}

const queueRegistry: { [key: string]: Queue<unknown> } = {};

 /*
 * The queue instance is singleton, meaning that only one instance of the queue is created for each unique combination of type, options.
 */

export function createQueue<T>(type: QueueType, options: QueueOptions): Queue<T> {
  // Create a unique key based on the type and option
  const key = `${type}-${JSON.stringify(options)}`;

  // more implementation
}

RabbitMQClient
// Purpose: Implementation of the QueueInterface for RabbitMQ.

/**
 * Creates a new instance of the RabbitMQ.
 */
export class RabbitMQClient<T> implements Queue<T> {


  constructor(exchange: string, url: string, config?: RabbitMQConfig) {
  }

  async connect(): Promise<void> {
    // not implemented
  }

  async send(message: T, routingKey: string = '', options: Options.Publish = {}): Promise<void> {
    // not implemented yet
  }

  async consume(
    callback: (message: T | null, error?: QueueError) => void,
    routingKey: string = '',
    queueName: string = ''
  ): Promise<void> {
    // not implemented yet
}

Everytime I create a Queue like:
  createQueue<T>(): Queue<T> {
    return QueueFactory.createQueue<T>(QueueFactory.QueueType.RABBITMQ, {
      url: process.env.RABBITMQ_URL!,
      exchange: process.env.RABBITMQ_EXCHANGE!,
      config: { durable: true, exchangeType: 'direct' }
    });
  }

const q1 = createQueue<String>
q1.send("hey, test queue"). // use same producer channel

const q2 = createQueue<number>
q2.send(1)        // use same producer channel

This will create the same instance for each Queue class. I need a producer who can use different channels for each message type. What should I do? Is the design itself a wrong choice like singleton?

It's not clear what you are asking here. I will note that declaring your generic in the class level implies that a single class instance will only ever handle the same generic type, the way your creator works (if it indeed returns a singleton) is kind of hacking around this limitation, and makes your choice of generic placement look wrong

This creates a single instance for each queue type and options. It is a multiton design pattern. Makes sense?
